# usb c thunderbolt to vga doesnt detect my extended laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, adapter, usb-3.1-type-c

Im using [lenovo ideapad gaming 3](https://www.theverge.com/21295596/lenovo-ideapad-gaming-3-review-laptop-budget-friendly-intel-10th-gen-nvidia-geforce-gtx) and the [ugreen 9 in 1 usb type c connector](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/i122935600-s128088849.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1).

It supports the thunderbolt, thats why I bought the usb type c to vga. Ive also tested the ugreen 9 in 1 type c with my samsung note 10+ and its working, so Im having doubts that the problem is in my laptop, not in the ugreen

Comment: Do you mean doesn't detect your external monitor?  What have you tried?  It won't necessarily automatically turn on.  After plugging it in, what shows on the display settings screen?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like even though it is a usb type c thunderbolt, its doesnt support extended display

I got the answer [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/Ideapad-Gaming-3-15ARH05-2-external-monitor-problem/m-p/5064956)

[image]